# Abrir pagina web en fecha predeterminada

Tags: html5, script

Calculo que debe ser un script para que llegada la fecha predeterminada, se abra otra página en vez de la página actual. Ej: index.html actual, llegado el 1º de enero no se muestre esa index.html sino index2.html. Usando el horario de la pc, notebook o celular que la este abriendo.
Muchas gracias  y saludos

Echando luz en el asunto: No tengo el script, normalmente se usa un script "refresh" en x milisengundos. Pero lo que quiero es: Tengo la pagina index.html actual, a ella colocarle un código (srcipt o php) que cuando llegue la fecha indicada (ej: 1/01/2018), automáticamente me abra "NO" ese index sino "otro" que ya tengo preparado de antemano. La fecha debería tomarse el del cliente que visita dicha página. O sea el servidor debería entregar "otro index" a partir de las 00.00 del 31/12/2017.
Mil gracias por la rápida respuesta.
Jdel

Comment: deberias mostrar el codigo que hayas probado hasta ahora.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? ¿Y la hora del servidor o del cliente? ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta aclarando esto y qué intentaste?

Answer (score 1):

Lo facil seria que el index actual lo deje de ser ( si es que en ella tienes todo el codigo), y solo agregarias una validacion, para depende de la fecha redirigir a uno u otro index ( que ya no se llamarian Index).